# How to Fill Emtpy space in Contour Plot?

Tags: python, contour

I have a CSV file containing X, Y, and Z values. I want to plot a contour plot using this dataset but unfortunately, there are some blank spaces that appear in my contour plot.

My data size is 184 X 3 where the x values range from 3 to 5, y value ranges from 16 to 25.

```
X      Y       Z
3     25.64  19.23
3     25.84  15.67
4     16.84  19.23
4     17.64  19.23
5     16.04  17.45
5     16.74  19.23
```

I have written the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13,10))   #fill the screen
ax = fig.gca()               # to work in 2d contour

x = contour_data['x']
y = contour_data['y']
z = contour_data['z']

xmax=(np.amax(x))
xmin=(np.amin(x))
ymax=(np.amax(y))
ymin=(np.amin(y))
zmax=(np.amax(z))
zmin=(np.amin(z))

z_surf = ((((x-(xmax+xmin)/2)/10)*((x-(xmax+xmin)/2)/10))/-1e6 + \
      (((y-(ymax+ymin)/2)/10*(y-(ymax+ymin)/2)/10))/-1e6 ) + zmin
zcorr=z-z_surf

X,Y= np.meshgrid(np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 51),np.linspace(ymin, ymax, 51))
Z = griddata((x, y), zcorr, (X, Y),method='linear')

im=ax.contourf(X, Y, Z,  15, alpha=.75, cmap = 'YlGnBu')
C = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 15, colors='black')

fig.colorbar(im,ax=ax)
plt.xticks()
plt.yticks()
plt.show()
```

The output that I receive is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvBPy.jpg
[image: Contour Plot]

Answer (score 0):

With some caution we can use `ax.set_fc(background_color)` to set up the default color of the axes. For the posted code I think something like this could work:

```
cmap = plt.cm.YlGnBu
background_color = cmap(1.0)   # the last color in cmap
ax.set_fc(background_color)
```